# XPath select all child nodes of the first child or an element?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to get a collection of li elements (child nodes) with Selenium using xpath but its returning null?

Javascript pseudo code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("jSC57  _6xe7A")[0].firstChild.childNodes
```

I want to get that in XPATH - but its returning null?

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='jSC57  _6xe7A']//div//li");
```

HTML sample:

```
<div class="isgrP">
    <ul class="jSC57  _6xe7A">
        <div class>
            <li class="wo9IH">
                <div class="li-container">
                    testing
                </div>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your `html` code please

Comment: @Pratik I've attached my html.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement `document.getElementsByClassName("jSC57  _6xe7A")[0].firstChild.childNodes`, I am making an assumption about what you want to retrieve here. `getElementsByClassName("jSC57  _6xe7A")` will return a list of `ul` element. Then, your `[0]` gets the first `ul`. `firstChild` will grab the first `div` element, and `childNodes` refers to the `li` elements that appear under `div`.

To get the `li` elements you are trying to retrieve from your tree, I might not use those class names -- they appear to be dynamic and might change each time you load the page.

I would use this XPath instead:

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul/div//li");
```

This will get all of the `div` nodes that appear under the `li` element.

But this might be too general for your purposes -- If you want to use the class name, you can modify as such:

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='jSC57  _6xe7A']/div/li");
```

Comment: I've updated my HTML as I forgot an element - could you revise your anwer? Thank you.

Comment: I'm also trying to get the li inside div not div inside li if that makes sense.

Comment: I see your updated HTML sample. I will update my answer. To clarify, I assumed that you were looking to retrieve a list of `li` elements, so that's how I re-formatted my answer.

Comment: Thank you, does `/li` mean only grabbing the first li, or all of them?

Comment: `/li` will grab all of them. To just grab the first one, you'd use `/li[1]`.